# Ffmpeg freezed while encoding 37mb video file from Action Camera

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gopro

I tried to encode three video files from my action camera and ffmpeg freezed. 
The video file was 37mb, without any prior manipulation.

```
 ffmpeg   -i GOPR0019.MP4 -i GOPR0019.MP4 -i GOPR0019.MP4 -filter_complex   "[0:v] scale=1920:1080, fps=50, vflip, hflip, setpts=0.33*PTS, fifo [v0]; \
  [0:v] scale=1920:1080,  setpts=0.33*PTS, fifo [v1];  
  [0:v] scale=1920:1080, fps=50, vflip, hflip, setpts=0.33*PTS, fifo [v2];  
  [v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1[out]" -map "[out]" -crf 14  -vcodec libx264  -vb 20M    video_out_01.avi
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GOPR0019.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
    location        : +38.0455+023.7321/
    location-eng    : +38.0455+023.7321/
    firmware        : HD5.02.02.60.00
  Duration: 00:00:05.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60245 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2704x1520 [SAR 1:1 DAR 169:95], 60140 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 38 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro MET
    Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 13 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro SOS
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GOPR0019.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
    location        : +38.0455+023.7321/
    location-eng    : +38.0455+023.7321/
    firmware        : HD5.02.02.60.00
  Duration: 00:00:05.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60245 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2704x1520 [SAR 1:1 DAR 169:95], 60140 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #1:3(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 38 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro MET
    Stream #1:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 13 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro SOS
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GOPR0019.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
    location        : +38.0455+023.7321/
    location-eng    : +38.0455+023.7321/
    firmware        : HD5.02.02.60.00
  Duration: 00:00:05.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60245 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2704x1520 [SAR 1:1 DAR 169:95], 60140 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #2:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 19:41:21:46
    Stream #2:3(eng): Data: none (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 38 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro MET
    Stream #2:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 13 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-12T19:41:21.000000Z
      handler_name    :     GoPro SOS
File 'video_out_01.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x564504a951a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x564504ae75a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x564504b3b0c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x564504212580] using SAR=1521/1520
[libx264 @ 0x564504212580] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x564504212580] profile High, level 4.2
Output #0, avi, to 'video_out_01.avi':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    firmware        : HD5.02.02.60.00
    location        : +38.0455+023.7321/
    location-eng    : +38.0455+023.7321/
    ISFT            : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1521:1520 DAR 169:95], q=-1--1, 20000 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/20000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Past duration 0.999992 too large
    Last message repeated 2 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large      6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6 speed=   0x    
    Last message repeated 9 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large      6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=26 speed=   0x    
    Last message repeated 9 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large      6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=47 speed=   0x    
    Last message repeated 9 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large      6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=67 speed=   0x    
    Last message repeated 9 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large      6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=87 speed=   0x    
Past duration 0.999992 too large      6kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=89 speed=   0x    
    Last message repeated 6 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large     518kB time=00:00:00.02 bitrate=212016.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=103 speed=0.00562x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large    1030kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=105433.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=109 speed=0.0194x    
    Last message repeated 5 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large    2054kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=84116.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=121 speed=0.0422x    
    Last message repeated 4 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large    2822kB time=00:00:00.30 bitrate=77049.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=131 speed=0.0572x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large    3334kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=75858.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=139 speed=0.0626x    
    Last message repeated 4 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large    4102kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=73044.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=148 speed=0.0723x    
    Last message repeated 5 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large    5126kB time=00:00:00.58 bitrate=72395.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=160 speed=0.083x    
    Last message repeated 4 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large    5894kB time=00:00:00.68 bitrate=71000.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=170 speed=0.0905x    
[Parsed_concat_15 @ 0x564504a8b820] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 5 times
```

Comment: ver 3.4 bugs had bugs with filtergraph fifo control. Upgrade to 4.2.

Comment: I am doing that right now. I hope will do the job!

Comment: @Gyan ffmpeg 4.2.3 did the job like a charm!!!! Thank you!